# insert a hyperlink into excel 2007 using VBA

Tags: excel, hyperlink

My worksheet "input" range "`B11`" has generated the destination URL:

```
file:///C:/Results/H1230-01%20VEF%201288.doc
```

My worksheet "input" range "`B10`" has generated the text:

```
H1230-01 VEF 1288
```

How can I automatically insert the hyperlink of the destination URL with the displayed text in a cell?:

```
Worksheets("VEF").Range("m65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HyperLink formula example:

```
=HYPERLINK("path","Text To Display")
```

Or with code:

```
Range.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""path"",""Text To Display"")
```

or Using your actual references use this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(B11,B10)
```

Comment: thank you - i wasnt aware of this function. i have no need to do this through VBA now. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use the `Hyperlink.Add` method, like in this example from Excel-Help

```
With Worksheets("VEF")
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("m65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
        Address:=.Range("B11"), _
        ScreenTip:="Microsoft Web Site", _
        TextToDisplay:=.Range("B10")
End With

With Worksheets(1)
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("a5"), _
        Address:="http://example.microsoft.com", _
        ScreenTip:="Microsoft Web Site", _
        TextToDisplay:="Microsoft"
End With
```